# Writing half equation confusion

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

The following is the answer for a question that I am doing:

> Reduction: $\ce{X^2+(aq) + 2 e- -> X(s)}$

Can I write $\ce{X + 2 e- -> X^2-}?$ Why can't I start with $\ce{X}$ instead of $\ce{X^2+}?$

EDIT: 
The question:

**Deduce the balanced equation for the voltaic cell constructed using metals B and C as electrodes.**

Context:
[image]

Comment: Those are two different things, you can not substitute one for the other

Comment: For starters, the second reaction may be impossible, because $\ce{B^{2-}}$ is not stable. If both reactions exist, they will happen at different electrochemical potentials, or voltages. Consider the real example of $\ce{Cu/Cu^+/Cu^{2+}}$.

Comment: What was the original question? Feel free to [edit] it in. Also, please avoid using generic clickbait-alike titles. The title must precisely reflect the essence of your question and don't bee too broad.

Comment: @andselisk I think there is a misunderstanding, that element is not Boron, I just mistakenly named it B. I changed the title and renamed that to element x. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Negrawh I made no assumption that it is, and it does not matter to my first comment. Now that you have edited in the question: I have never seen a metal-based anion either.

Comment: Going by a car from place A to place B can be replaced by arriving at place B from place A, not by going from place B to place C that does not even exist..

Comment: @Poutnik Sorry sir, I don't get the analogy.

Comment: How so ? Place A = X2+, place B = X,  place C = X2-  :-) We do not know stable metallic anions in water solutions. Unless you mean X = M2+, what would be very unusual and contraintuitive convention and as such strongly not recommended. Chemists are used to symbols carrying their true elementary charge and not the charge transposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I write $\ce{X + 2 e- -> X^2-}?$ Why can't I start with $\ce{X}$ instead of $\ce{X^2+}?$

The question says that the metals are $\ce{A(s), B(s), C(s) and D(s)}$. That means the letters stand for the uncharged element, not for something more arbitrary. In the table, the letters are used again, in the following way (shown for A):

$$\ce{A(NO3)2(aq)}$$

Because nitrate has a negative charge, the metal A forms an ion in water with a positive 2 charge ($\ce{A^2+}$).

$$\ce{A(NO3)2(s) -> A^2+(aq) + 2NO3-(aq)}$$

With the same argument, you can figure out that B also forms a divalent cation in solution, while C and D are monovalent. There is no flexibility of having $\ce{A}$ stand for an ion, or for the formation of a metal anion; you should stick to the species and symbols in the text and table of the question.

**Examples where letters stand for something else**

In acid/base chemistry, A and B are used in the following way:

$$\ce{AH <=> A- + H+}$$

$$\ce{B + H+ <=> BH+}$$

If you look closely, $\ce{B}$ stands for a base (with conjugate acid $\ce{BH+}$) and - which might cause confusion - $\ce{AH}$ stands for an acid (with conjugate base $\ce{A-}$). Neither A nor B have to be a single atom, and their charge could be anything. However, $\ce{B}$ and $\ce{A-}$ have one charge less than $\ce{BH+}$ and $\ce{AH}$, respectively.

In redox (bio)chemistry, $\ce{NADH and NAD+}$ are used. Again, the charges are to be interpreted as relative, and the relationship between the two is given by:

$$\ce{NAD+ + H+ + 2e- <=> NADH}$$

Comment: Hey sir thank you for the answer! I answered the question: can you check whether it is correct? The balanced equation using B and C as electrodes is: $2C + B^{2+} --> B + 2C^+$ How come the reactant side looks like the product side? Is it still correct and does this occur often? Many thanks!

Comment: @Negrawh The reactant side looks like the product side because in a balanced equation, you have the same type and number of atoms on both sides. In this case, the only difference is the transfer of electrons (no hetero-atomic covalent bonds made or broken, just going from metallic element to ions and reverse), so the only indication of the reaction is a change in charges.

Answer (score 0):

A is Zinc or Iron. C is Copper. B is Silver. I don't know what is D.

The reason is that when dipped in Cu2+ or Ag+ solution, a piece of iron or zinc reacts with both and produces a metallic deposit of Cu or Ag. 
A metallic strip of silver never reacts with Zn2+ or Cu2+.
A metallic strip of Copper reacts with a Ag+ solution, producing a nice silver deposit. And it does not react with Zn2+.